# Create custom radio buttons programmatically

Tags: android

I want to make a custom radio button in code rather than in xml file because my project will be exported to a jar file.

Comment: Why do you need to export it as a jar file, particularly when there exists the [AAR format](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format) specifically for single bundles of both code and resources?

Comment: The jar file will be used as a sdk.

Comment: AARs can be used as an SDK as well you know.

Answer (score 0):

Just create it with new like any other object.  Then you (or the caller) will need to add it to the layout.

Comment: Then where should I set the style?

Comment: After you new it.  Anything you can set in the xml can be added via a function as well.

Comment: My project would be exported as a jar file and to be used as a sdk, so xml file is not allowed.

Comment: ANd where did I mention xml?  Every layout is an object as well.